# How can I include CSS in php?

Tags: php, css

i want to include my css/stylesheet via php so that...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mydomain.com/css/style.php">
```

so that i can than dynamicly change different stylesheets.... how can i do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you set your MIME type in `style.php` to CSS, you should be in business.  Add this to the very top:

```
<?php Header ("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");?>
```

Another option if you're running on an Apache server is to tell it to check .css files for PHP.  Add this to your `.htaccess` file to do this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

Then you could simply include a regular .css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mydomain.com/css/style.css">
```

Comment: i didnot understant if i have setup all these things then why should i include style.css instead of style.php

Comment: Don’t forget to specify the character set.

Comment: @testkhan the second example was just showing you how you could get your Apache web server to check .css files for PHP.  However setting the correct MIME type in your `style.php` should allow your original code example to work.  I've updated my first example with Gumbo's suggestion of setting the charset at the same time.

Comment: Making .css files parsed as PHP doesn't look much of good idea, in my opinion. +1 for the rest of the answer. Spot On.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this php code in your html head section but file should be .php.

For example: **index.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
   <?php

     $cssFile = "style.css";
     echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $cssFile . "'>";

   ?>
   </head>
   <body>
    ...
    ...
   </body>
</html>
```

You can store any css file path in `$cssFile` variable using different conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In style.php:

```
echo file_get_contents('style.css');
```

This will just output the contents of `style.css`.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of dynamically changing the page style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/<?php echo $user['style']; ?>.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

### Add multiple CSS files dynamicly

The answers seem to be different that they question...
If you want to add all CSS files in the CSS map and not have to worry about changing the code whenever a css file name changes or another one is added, use:

```
 <?php
     foreach(glob("CSS/*.css") as $css_file)
     {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css_file.'" type="text/css" medial="all"  />';
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do it the other way around and just include a different css file in your php?

```
print "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$path_to_css_file'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly include CSS into a HTML file:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php include 'stylesheet.php'; ?>
</style>
```