# How can i make php file to use as css in zend?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, w3c-validation

I refer the following link,

[How can I include CSS in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483213/how-can-i-include-css-in-php)

I am using zend. In my template phtml file, i include like below,

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type="button"] {
        background-image: url("<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/images/sub_bg-green.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        border: 1px solid #4B8109;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        color:#000;   
    }
</style>
```

code `<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>` will give base url. This works when i include inside template page. Now i am working on w3c validation which gives error. so i tried to put all styles in `product_details.php` and include it in phtml file  by using following code,

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/templates/product_details.php');  ?>
```

when i view the source code of file, i did not get the base url, instead i got like below,

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type="button"] {
        background-image: url("SITE_URL/images/sub_bg-green.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        border: 1px solid #4B8109;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        color:#000;   
    }
</style>
```

How can i include php code in css and at the same time it should be inside `<HEAD>` so that we can achieve w3c validation.Kindly advice on this.

Comment: Where are you defining the `BASE_URL` and `SITE_URL` constants?

Comment: @Phill I define in index.php like define('BASE_URL', $config->baseurl);
define('SITE_URL', $config->siteurl.BASE_URL);

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use relative links from the CSS file to the images, eg

```
/* Assuming CSS file is css/templates/product_details.css */

background-image: url(../../images/sub_bg-green.jpg);
```

... or even an absolute URL if your images are always in the same place

```
background-image: url(/images/sub_bg-green.jpg);
```

You then just link the CSS file using the `HeadLink` view helper

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(
    $this->baseUrl('css/templates/product_detail.css')); ?>
```