# How can I run a PHP script in a .css file and it will be fully working?

Tags: php, css

I've been editing the .css file trying to make php codes working but when i put them normally it comes up like a normal text , i want to know can i run a php file in a .css file? if yes will it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i run PHP inside CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367134/how-do-i-run-php-inside-css)

Comment: and more commonly: [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4687208)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");

// and echo your CSS code...
```

But don't do it, it's not worth it. Just save the dynamic CSS to a CSS file every time it changes

Comment: I want to do the opposite , I wan't to make a .css file run a php file inside it?