# Reading values from css

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I'd like to get the colours from my database and put it directly into the css page. I don't want to put them as additional  tag into the php. If possible, I'd like to read directly from css... Is that possible? I'm using php + mySQL + css + html 5....
The reason is because, in the future, I'd like to add different skins for the same php and I want to be free to change completely the design. Any clue?
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i run PHP inside CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367134/how-do-i-run-php-inside-css)

Comment: I don't think so because I don't want to change the values from the PHP. Actually, I'm doing like this. I just wanna know if possible to read the information directly from CSS. I mean, without any modification of php with tags like 'style'

Comment: the referenced answer describes how you can add php into a css file. Without php you can't read anything from the database. So if you want to do this, then you need what is described within the referenced answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide). If you want to the change colors you can define them as variables and easily change everything at once.

Comment: THANK YOU! I think it will be useful!

Comment: For whom might interest I found this and.... it works!!! http://librosweb.es/css_avanzado/capitulo_6/variables_en_las_hojas_de_estilos.html