# Add space between two tables in php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have this php script:

```
<?php
$gene = $_POST["gene"];

$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","emi22mar6","refGene");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_select_db($enlace,"refGene_human");
$result = mysqli_query($enlace,"select * from refGene_human where name2 like '%$gene%'");

echo "<h1>RefGene Results</h1>";

echo "<table align='left' cellspacing=3 cellpadding=4 border=1 bgcolor=dddddd>";
echo "<tr align='center'><th>Transcript</th><th>Gene</th><th>Chromosome</th><th>Strand</th><th>Gene_Start</th><th>Gene_End</th><th>CDS_Start</th><th>CDS_End</th><th>ExonCount</th>";
while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$extraido['name']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido['name2']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$extraido['chrom']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$extraido['strand']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='right'>".$extraido['txStart']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='right'>".$extraido['txEnd']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='right'>".$extraido['cdsStart']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='right'>".$extraido['cdsEnd']."<br/>";
echo "<td align='right'>".$extraido['exonCount']."<br/>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($enlace);


$enlace2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","emi22mar6","refGene");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


mysqli_select_db($enlace2,"go_association_human");
$result2 = mysqli_query($enlace2,"select * from go_association_human where db_object_symbol like '%$gene%'");

echo "<h1>GO_Association Results</h1>";

echo "<table align='left' cellspacing=3 cellpadding=4 border=1 bgcolor=dddddd>";
echo "<tr align='center'><th>DB</th><th>Gene_ID</th><th>Gene_Symbol</th><th>GO_id</th><th>GO_reference</th><th>Association</th><th>Type</th><th>Date</th><th>Assigned_by</th>";

while ($extraido2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['db']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['db_object_id']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['db_object_symbol']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['go_id']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['db_reference']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['db_object_name']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['db_object_type']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['date']."<br/>";
echo "<td>".$extraido2['assigned_by']."<br/>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_free_result($result2);

mysqli_close($enlace);
?>
```

Which generates two tables, but I would like to add space between them, so that the second title "Association Results", gets between both tables and separating them, as if this title was above the second table. The code, as it is now, generates two consecutive tables with no spacing between them and putting the second title next to the first table...

I know the solution involves adding some margin to the tables via css or something similar, like adding this kind of code:

```
<style type="text/css">
table{
  margin: 10px 0;
}
</style>
```

But I do not know how to integrate that css code into the php script so that it affects both tables.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You can include CSS anywhere on your page. You do not need to echo it out in PHP.

Comment: `<td align='right'>".$X."<br/>` you need to close off those with `</td>`'s and not `<br/>`'s. what you have now is invalid html markup. You're also missing closing `</tr>`'s.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually, `</td>` and `</tr>` are optional.

Comment: @MrLister not good practice and some browsers will even throw something about it.

Comment: @MrLister Anyway `</td>` is optional _if the td element is immediately followed by a td or th element, or if there is no more content in the parent element_ (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html/tabular-data.html#the-td-element).

Comment: @MrLister **In no way is WELL FORMED HTML optional**, specially if you want bullet-proof layout

Comment: @MrLister Interesting that it will validate in HTML but not XHTML. So I guess we're both kind of right and wrong at the same while ;-) TBH, I had to research this a bit more and found this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/4020374/1415724 and about that "XHTML" http://stackoverflow.com/a/4020384/1415724

Comment: @Fred-ii- But the OP's source is not XHTML, so there's not need to bring XHTML into it. If you want to complain about errors, there are plenty of real errors in the OP's source!

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's what the rules say. Don't blame the messenger.

Comment: @MrLister I know that, but what if at some point it does? We don't know what they're going to do in the future, unless you threw me one of those fancy crystal balls ;-) let's just agree to disagree then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm just surprised that of all the things wrong with the OP's source, you chose these to point out. Why not mention the `bgcolor` attribute, the missing `#` on the color value, etc. Oh, and don't get me started about echoing unescaped values from the datebase.

Comment: @MrLister I'd of have to submit an answer to outline all their errors because there isn't enough space inside the "one comment" box. I chose not to, fearing being chased down a potential deep rabbit hole; this one's all yours ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include CSS in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483213/how-can-i-include-css-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

can you check this: create a .css file and add a class with some meaningful name like .resultTable.
add the class for table in php code as below

```
echo "<table class="\"resultTable"\" align='left' cellspacing=3 cellpadding=4 border=1 bgcolor=dddddd>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<table align='left' cellspacing=3 cellpadding=4 border=1 bgcolor=dddddd>
```

actually floats the first table to the left.
See the definition of [`align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-align-TABLE) in `table`.

Solution: remove the `align='left'` from the start tag.

```
<table cellspacing=3 cellpadding=4 border=1 bgcolor="#dddddd">
```